# Maven Dependency with type tag cannot be imported

Tags: java, maven

I am using the [TeleSign dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.telesign/telesign/0.6.0). According to the Maven Repository, it tells me to use the dependency as follows:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.telesign</groupId>
  <artifactId>telesign</artifactId>
  <version>0.6.0</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

However, I add it to my POM and reimport. The package is not downloaded. After searching, I found the reason is the tag `<type>` is `pom`. Remove it and import is not.

So my question is that **why the official maven repository add this `<type>pom</type>` in the dependency**? Is there any other things to think about or just an error?

I have searched the related questions such as https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-purpose-to-use-type-in-a-maven-dependency. So I have known the usage of `type`. I just don't understand why they add this `<type>pom</type>` tag in the dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is useful in a `<dependencyManagement>` section.

More info here: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html